# owner is not able the access the file

Tags: linux, permissions, redhat

in Linux the root user have a folder (ex./share) **in this folder other user have no permission .but if i create a file in this folder and make owner of the file to some other user still other user will not able to access that file  (***of which it is owner***)**

Comment: i want to know the logic of this

Comment: Voting to close : "Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a **clear problem statement* are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" .....

Comment: ....  Also, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,    and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: First of all `root` should not share stuff! Nonetheless, the users do not have permissions to access `share`, hence they cannot see the file!

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be in the directory permission. Please make sure that the user have access to the directory that the file is in.

If your folder is /share , you can allow other user to access it as follow :

## chmod o+rX /share

Comment: thanks. but your logic is wrong it is all about accessing the inode table